# Using tikzuml to create a umlclass with two types

Tags: tikz-uml

I want to create a uml class in my tex document, where I have two types, so basically two arguments with << >> symbols on each side, but the second one on a different line. I checked the tikzuml docs but couldn't find anything to solve this.

Edit: As a user mentioned to also add a sketch too my question to better understand my problem, here is one: [image: example]

Comment: Welcome. // @SlothOnCrack, as your question is hard to understand the way it's now, I suggest to mock-up a drawing or sketch, which clarifies what you mean by the "<< >> symbols".

Comment: @MS-SPO Thank you for pointing that out. I edited my post

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The easiest is to manually insert closing brackets, a line ending, opening brackets and the second line into the type specification:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz-uml}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture} 
\umlemptyclass[type=interface$\gg$\\$\ll$second line]{class-name} 
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]